# Boundedness of solution of second kind Volterra integral equation (Proof verification )

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, solution-verification, integral-equations

Consider the following second kind Volterra integral equation
$$x(t)=\int_0^tk(s,t)x(s)ds+f(t),$$
where $f$ is continuous on $[0,T]$ and $k$ is continuous kernel for all $0\leq s\leq 0 \leq t \leq T$.

Assume that there exists a positive number $m$ such that    $$\int_0^t|k(s,t)|ds\leq m<1$$
then there exists a positive number $c$ such that $$sup|x(t)|\leq c|f(t)|.$$

My proof is as the following: If the last estimate is not true, then we have for any $c>0$
 $$sup|x(t)|>c|f(t)|.$$
From the integral equation, we have the estimate
$$sup|x(t)|\leq sup|x(t)| \int_0^t|k(s,t)|ds+|f(t)|,$$
thus, $$1\leq \int_0^t|k(s,t)|ds+\frac{1}{c}.$$
Now, letting c tends to $\infty$ we get
$$1 \leq \int_0^t|k(s,t)|ds,$$
which contradicts the assumption. Is that right?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is correct.  Although, a more fluent way of doing it as follows.
\begin{align}
\sup |x(t)| &\leq \sup |x(t)|\int_0^t |k(s,t)|\, ds +|f(t)| \\
&\leq  \sup |x(t)|m +|f(t)|. 
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
(1-m)\sup |x(t)|\leq|f(t)| \\
\implies \sup|x(t)|\leq \frac{|f(t)|}{1-m}.
\end{align}
This gets out a bound explicitly.

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer.

Comment: No problem. By the way, as an exercise, see if you can prove the function $T(x)=\int_0^t k(s,t)x(s)\, ds + f(t)$ is a contraction mapping under the hypotheses.